# Convert data to Chart using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, charts

i have a table named `cell_daily` in my database where the records are
[image: here]

i want to convert this data to a chart using php just like this [image: chart example]

i am stucked when i use `date` column as xAxis it always loops. can you guys help me solve this problem and what chart should i use?
fyi : the table always be updated by user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Use a javascript chart library like chart-c3.
2. Get database rows by php and echo them into js var.
3. load that js var via chart

Comment: i did,in this case i use highchart library. when i echo to js var column date and cellname always looping for example date  it will return 2019-07-01 2019-07-01 2019-07-01 to the end.

Comment: use implod or foreach loop to convert array to string and use  string  ','  as glue.